# How do I use a hexadecimal value to specify the color in a LinearGradient in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

```
    ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory sf = new ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory() {
        @Override
        public Shader resize(int width, int height) {
            LinearGradient lg = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, border.getHeight(),
                new int[] { 
                    Color.CYAN, 
                    Color.WHITE, 
                    Color.WHITE
                    }, //substitute the correct colors for these
                new float[] {
                    0, 0.45f, 0.55f, 1 },
                Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
             return lg;
        }
    }
```

In this code instead of using `Color.CYAN` I want to insert a hexadecimal value for the color. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new int[] {
    Color.parseColor("#00FFFF"),
    Color.WHITE,
    Color.WHITE
 },
```

Comment: It says that the constructor(int,int,int) is not defined. How do i define it?

Comment: I dunno. Needed it for the gradient effect..How do I define 1 int??

Comment: Constructor (int) is not defined..So in any case the constructor needs to be defined..